# Buck Converter Gain Margin and Phase Margin Review

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, buck

I am using this IC ([MPQ4470](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/mpq4470-aec1.html)) for designing a buck converter (12 to 5 V - 3 A). Below is my circuit.

[image]

I am checking the stability of this circuit. My phase gain plot is given below.

[image]

My PM is 92 degree and GM is 39.8 dB. I know that for a stable system GM and PM should be positive.

If GM and PM is too high response will be sluggish. (Please correct me if I am wrong)

May I know the obtained GM and PM is fine or do I need to reduce the PM.

If yes may I know how to reduce PM?

**As suggested by Andy and Verbal Kint,I run the simulation from 10Hz to 1Mhz.**

Please see the plot below.

[image]

Comment: Did you not consider using different colours for PM and GM in the plot?

Comment: @Andyaka,Updated the plot

Comment: Yes, I concur with *Andy*'s comment (black for the mag and red for the phase for instance) and on top of that, it is easier to interpret if you center the 0 dB and the 0° phase response like +40/-40 dB for the mag plot and +180°/-180° for the phase response. Also, usually an ac plot between 10 and 100 kHz does well as you can see the dc gain (what we don't really see here).

Comment: Yes, as per @VerbalKint comment let's see the response all the way from 10 Hz to HF. Then we will see the true nature of the phase shift with respect to near-DC values.

Comment: @VerbalKint,Updated the plot.I run the simulation from 10Hz to 1Mhz.Could you please check

Comment: @Andyaka,Updated the plot.I run the simulation from 10Hz to 1Mhz.Could you please check

Comment: The Bode plot looks good to me but I am surprised by the 20-dB dc gain which is an extremely low value for good dc regulation. Also I usually use a simple resistance to load the converter for ac analysis, not a current source. You can plot the closed-loop output impedance to check the absence of peaking as your crossover is lower than the resonant frequency of the \$LC\$ filter.

Comment: @VerbalKint,Thank you.I am new to SIMPLIS May I know how to plot the closed-loop output impedance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *May I know the obtained GM and PM is fine or do I need to reduce the
> PM*

Now that you've shown the response from 10 Hz (can be regarded as DC), it's possible to ascertain the GM and PM from the graph: -

[image]

So, this ties in with the calculated numbers.

It's always worth doing it manually (double checking). So, both PM and GM are fine but, as per **Verbal Kint**'s comment, the DC gain is a bit low and, this means weakened voltage regulation. And, it should **not be** a problem if DC gain was increased by (say) another 20 dB; PM would drop from a very healthy 90° to a "still good" value of around 50° <-- can you see how I've estimated that? If not, I'll draw you another graph.

However, the MPQ4470 is a synchronous buck regulator and, it will naturally have fairly good regulation based on the fact that it is a synchronous regulator.

Comment: "If not, I'll draw you another graph.",it will be very helpful if you can draw the graph

Comment: Try this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MKIg.png <-- I've just shifted down the y-axis scale on the amplitude plot and redrawn where the 0 dB (unity gain) line will be. Then projected that point onto the phase plot to get a new PM of around 45 degrees. But. remember that it is an estimate; you should really increase DC loop gain and see how it pans out with a new plot of things.

Comment: If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: May I know how to increase the DC loop gain

Comment: I'm not an expert on that chip. Possibly you can't change the loop gain; maybe it's fixed. I'm just not familiar with the device @Hari